# Can I use VBA to disable a check box with a condition that is based on a text in a combo box?

Tags: ms-access

I have a combo box `cpm` and a checkbox `cpm_meth_culture`. If `cpm` is "No", then I'd like to disable the checkbox `cpm_meth_culture`. Is this possible?

I've tried the following with visual basic, but it's not doing anything:

```
Private Sub cpm_AfterUpdate()
    If Me.cpm = "No" Then
        Me.cpm_meth_culture.Enabled = False
    Else
        Me.cpm_meth_culture.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the issue. The cpm combo box is in bit format with yes/no options for row source. Since it's stored as a bit, then the code has to be:

```
Private Sub cpm_AfterUpdate()
    If Me.cpm = 0 Then
        Me.cpm_meth_culture.Enabled = False
    Else
        Me.cpm_meth_culture.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Could be one line: `Me.cpm_meth_culture.Enabled = Me.cpm <> 0`

Comment: wow thanks @KostasK.! Still learning over here, so I appreciate it!